# How to make BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets ARC compatible?

Tags: ios, ios6

I came across this rewarding UIAlerts in Cocoa Controls.

https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

After I implemented the  installation it doesn't seem to be ARC compatible yet.

Anyone figured this out?

Comment: You could always disable ARC for just those files.

Comment: You can probably direct your questions to the issues forum: https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets/issues It also looks like some developers have already tackled this for you: https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets/pull/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable ARC for individual files by adding the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for those files. Please check the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project).